# Spark Application Using Scala IDE

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'm trying to run Spark classifier using scala on my machine but I am getting the following error:

> Only one SparkContext may be running in this JVM (see SPARK-2243). To
>   ignore this error, set spark.driver.allowMultipleContexts = true.

Comment: seems like you are creating multiple sparkContext instances. If you want more help update with your code ie. what you've tried so far.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spark multiple contexts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32827333/spark-multiple-contexts)