# How to have more StreamingContexts in a single Spark application?

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

I'm trying to run a spark streaming job on the spark-shell, localhost. Following the code from [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/streaming-programming-guide.html) this is what I first tried:

```
import org.apache.spark._
import org.apache.spark.streaming._
import org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext._ 

val conf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local[2]").setAppName("NetworkWordCount")
val ssc = new StreamingContext(conf, Seconds(30))
```

Which gives following errors:

> org.apache.spark.SparkException: Only one SparkContext may be running in
>   this JVM (see SPARK-2243). To ignore this error, set spark.driver.allowMultipleContexts = true.

And so I had to try this:

```
import org.apache.spark._
import org.apache.spark.streaming._
import org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext._ 

val conf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local[2]").setAppName 
("NetworkWordCount").set("spark.driver.allowMultipleContexts", "true")
val ssc = new StreamingContext(conf, Seconds(30))
```

This runs but with the following warning:

> 2018-05-17 17:01:14 WARN  SparkContext:87 - Multiple running SparkContexts detected in the same JVM!

So I'd like to know if there might be another way of declaring a `StreamingContext` object that does not require `allowMulipleContexts == True` as it appears using multiple contexts is [discouraged](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32827333/spark-multiple-contexts)? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the existing SparkContext `sc` to create the [StreamingContext](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/streaming/StreamingContext.html#StreamingContext-org.apache.spark.SparkContext-org.apache.spark.streaming.Duration-)

```
val ssc = new StreamingContext(sc, Seconds(30))
```

When you create it using the alternate constructor i.e the one with `SparkConf` it internally creates another `SparkContext` and that's why you get that Warning.