# PySpark : question from a beginner about spark context

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

i'm trying to understand how Spark wprks and I'm learning PySpark.

I know know Python and the Pandas library.

I understand that if I want to read a big cvs file with Pandas usin dataframe, it may not work (or it will take a long time to read).

As such PySpark is an alternative.

I read some artcicles and I understaoof the first thing to do is to create a SparkContext.

I understant the SparkContext will manage the cluster which will read the csv file and transform datas.

So I hade this code in a juptyter notebook
`# Import de SparkContext du module pyspark`
`from pyspark import SparkContext`

`sc = SparkContext('local')`
`sc`

if i execute this code twice,t he 2nd time I will get an error because I cant' have 2 spark contexts.
Why can't i have 2 sparks contexts?

I wanted to try this:
`# Import de SparkContext du module pyspark`
`from pyspark import SparkContext`

`sc1 = SparkContext('local')`

`sc2 = SparkContext('local')`

I have 2 different names: sc1 and sc2. Even if execute only one time, I have an error. Why cant' I have 2 sparks context sc1and sc2?

thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spark multiple contexts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32827333/spark-multiple-contexts)

Answer (score 0):

Yes thats right , you cant. Thats why Spark Session was developed.
Only one SparkContext should be active per JVM. You must stop() the active SparkContext before creating a new one.
SparkContext instance is not supported to share across multiple processes out of the box, and PySpark does not guarantee multi-processing execution. Use threads instead for concurrent processing purpose.

Please also see the below relevant article:
[https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.SparkContext.html#:~:text=Only%20one%20SparkContext%20should%20be,not%20guarantee%20multi%2Dprocessing%20execution](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.SparkContext.html#:%7E:text=Only%20one%20SparkContext%20should%20be,not%20guarantee%20multi%2Dprocessing%20execution).

Please go through this very good article for your enhance knowledge on Spark context and Session:

https://medium.com/@akhilasaineni7/exploring-sparkcontext-and-sparksession-8369e60f658e